# Need help making a door open with an animation instead of scripted rotations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 3d

My door is opening funny with the script, so I would like to open it with animation instead. If anyone knows how to fix this, that'd be super helpful. Here's the part of the script controlling the open door section.

I've tried scripting it but I can't seem to find the right scripting method for Unity. (I'm using the newest version of Unity).

```
 if (open)
        {
            var newRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, -90.0f, 0f), Time.deltaTime * 200);
            transform.rotation = newRot;

            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, interactDistance))
            {
                if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Door"))
                {
                hit.collider.transform.parent.GetComponent<doorOpen>().ChangeDoorState();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var newRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f), Time.deltaTime * 200);
            transform.rotation = newRot;
        }
```

I'm using a key to open my door, and I would like for the door to open with an animation. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: I suggest you read/watch a [tutorial on how to use animations](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/animation). Stackoverflow is a platform to help with issues you encounter while you are trying to achieve something and not to do the work for you. Research the subject and try to do it on your own. If you have any concrete problems you can always ask a question here. I suggest you do the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would create and animation that changed the desired transform of the game object. (In your case, Y rotation.)

Then in the animator window, set a trigger that would call that animation and then call it when the correct RayCast hits it. You can create conditional logic to play it in reverse, or create a close animation as well.

```
    animator.setTrigger("Open");
```

The advantage of doing it this way, is you can easily control the speed of the door's opening.

Comment: so I would put this?
if (open)
    {
        animator.setTrigger("Open")
    }

Comment: Yes, and then your else would be either a reverse of that Animation or a close animation. I would recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an animation clip with the door and save it
2. Add an animation component with the door gameobject
3. then put there the animation you've created

Answer (score 0):

hit.collider.transform.parent.GetComponent().ChangeDoorState();
should have triggered an animation. Not this.

```
private Animator _animator;

void Start()
{
    _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    _animator.SetBool("open", true);
}
```

the "'open'" is the animation you assign to the door.
make sure to add on 'animator' in the inspector.